# Numbered list is not preserved while converting html file to docx file using pypandoc

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pandoc, pypandoc

I am trying to convert my **HTML** file to **docx** using **pypandoc** library of python. But while converting HTML file to docx the **numbered list** is not preserving in docx file.

**Numbered List in HTML File:**

[image]

**Numbered List in docx file:**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pypandoc
pypandoc.convert('Outline.html', 'docx', outputfile='Outline.docx')
```

Also tried using:

```
pypandoc.convert_file('Outline.html', 'docx', outputfile='Outline.docx')
```

I am using the following environment:

```
pypandoc 1.4  # Installed using pip
pandoc 1.12.2.1
OS : Ubuntu 14.04
Python Version : Python 2.7
```

I tried using following versions of libraries also:

```
pypandoc 1.3
pandoc 2.0
pandoc 2.4
pandoc 2.5
```

Please refer the attached files for more clarification:

> HTML file : [Outline.html](https://www.mediafire.com/file/8xkk71gkq9s7n9y/Outline.html/file)
>
> Generated Docx file : [Outline.docx](https://www.mediafire.com/file/wnw6w34ow4abby3/Outline.docx/file)

**Does anyone have any suggestions for converting HTML file to docx file with numbered list preserved using pypandoc ?**

Thank you.

Comment: The software versions are ancient, this is likely to be fixed by updating. Please insert the relevant HTML snippets into the question instead of linking to a file on a third party server.

Comment: I am using latest `pypandoc` version and also tried with different versions of `pypandoc` and `pandoc`. And HTML file contents are too big that's why I preferred to link the file url.

Comment: If you tried different versions, then please add this information to your question. Pandoc 1.12.2.1 was released almost exactly 5 years ago. The fact that the file is too large was part of my point, which I admittedly should have made clearer. It is difficult to help if one has to first pin-point the relevant HTML code. A question is more likely to be answered if it doesn't require a lot of work on the side of people trying to help you.

Comment: Hi @tarleb, Thanks for suggestions. I have updated question according to your suggestions. The issue is not reproducible if I remove some of data from HTML file, So I couldn't make it smaller and post in question.